# I can't move Movieclip by .x properity

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, movieclip

I have a little bug and I can't figure out ho to repair it. in my array 'youreq' i have objects with structure {ID:Object, name:String, Q:int}. My code is:

```
for each (var num in youreq)
{
trace(num.ID); //Object 1a8e191
trace("x"+num.ID.x); //x355.15
trace("y"+num.ID.y); //y108.45
trace(tns); //36
num.ID.x -=  tns;
num.ID.visible = false; //nothing changed...
trace(num.ID.x); //319.15
}
```

but nothings happens (I want to move MovieClip 6 pixels in left, but also toggling visibility doesn't work). Could anybody help me? :)

Answer (score 2):

Try to cast num.ID to MovieClip. And make sure that num.ID is MovieClip.

```
for each (var num in youreq)
{
trace(num.ID); //Object 1a8e191
trace("x"+num.ID.x); //x355.15
trace("y"+num.ID.y); //y108.45
trace(tns); //36
trace (num.ID is MovieClip) // check if the ID object is MovieClip
MovieClip(num.ID).x -=  tns;
MovieClip(num.ID).visible = false; //nothing changed...

trace(num.ID.x); //319.15
}
```

Comment: trace (num.ID is MovieClip); // true
both Object have the same @1a8e191 in debugger

Comment: `trace(num.ID.parent)`. Perhaps that ID is plain unadded to anywhere.

Comment: 'trace(num.ID.parent)' gives 'null' response

Comment: 'trace(num.ID.parent)' gives 'null' - this means that num.ID movieclip is not added to any DisplayObjectContainer, and it can not be displayed (you should not see that clip).

Comment: strange, because I've previously addChild() with that Objects, any they are on the screen (works previous added Events Listeners)